# Need to populate text values from related object to parent object text field

Tags: visual-workflow, workflow, opportunity, opportunity-lineitem

The requirement was whenever a product is added to an opportunity the product's product family text values need to be populated in the opportunity object itself in a custom text field named products_on_opportunity_c. If multiple products are added to an opportunity the product family values are separated using ";" . Whenever added the values need to be added and removed when the product is removed.

So far I have tried with record-triggered flow is :

- Created a record triggered flow in the object `Opportunitylineitem` where it triggers when record is updated or created

  - no conditions added
  - optimize the flow for action and related records (after save)
- Used a Decision element if the `opportunitylineitem.opportunityid` is changed or not.

  - If `$record.opportunityid` does not equal to `$record-prior.opportunityid`
  - When to Execute Outcome: Only if the record that triggered the flow to run is updated to meet the condition requirements
- If Id changes then it is connected to another element Get records element

  - conditions are if `opportunity Id` equals to `$record.opportuntiyid` then get the records from the `opportunitylineitem` object and keep the get records element in loop for each the assignment element
- (here I have created a record variable to store values "all the products " assigned the all the products variable to store the loop values AND ";" in the variable .
- Then after last item used the update records elements to update opportunity object with conditions if `id` equals `$record.opportunityid`
- then (Used another variable formula variable where it stores the values with formula:

  ```
  LEFT({!alltheproducts},LEN({!alltheproducts})-2)
  ```

  the formula variable name `removelastsemicolon`)
- if the condition of ID met then assign the products_on_opportunity record with values of the formula variable `removelastsemicolon`.

The flow had no errors but when I have tried adding the products the values are not populating in the opportunity object's custom field. Can anyone help me to solve this

[image]

[image]

[image]

After the flow is debugged. the below are the dbug details :

- This debug run was triggered as if the opportunitylineitem record was created.
  Rahul Reddy (0055j000001qbUZ) started the flow interview.
  API Version for Running the Flow: 56
  Some of this flow's variables were set when the interview started.
  $Record = OpportunityLineItem (00k5j00000ftwmEAAQ)
- Decision if changed
  Outcome executed: if_id_changed
  Outcome conditions

Does Require Record Changed to meet criteria: true
{!$Record.OpportunityId} (0065j00000wJCU6AAO) Does not equal {!$Record__Prior.OpportunityId} (null)
All conditions must be true (AND)

- Get records element
  Find all OpportunityLineItem records where

OpportunityId Equals {!$Record.OpportunityId} (0065j00000wJCU6AAO)
Store the values of these fields in get_opp_values: Product_family__c, Id
Result

Successfully found records.

- Loop Through: [00k5j00000fuSwYAAU,00k5j00000ftwmEAAQ,00k5j00000fuSwTAAU,00k5j00000fuSwOAAU]
  Iteration: 0
  Current iteration item: 00k5j00000fuSwYAAU
- Assignment
  {!alltheproducts} Add {!oppprod.Product_family__c}
  {!alltheproducts} Add ;
  Result

{!alltheproducts} = ";"

- Loop Through: [00k5j00000fuSwYAAU,00k5j00000ftwmEAAQ,00k5j00000fuSwTAAU,00k5j00000fuSwOAAU]
  Iteration: 1
  Current iteration item: 00k5j00000ftwmEAAQ
- Assignment
  {!alltheproducts} Add {!oppprod.Product_family__c}
  {!alltheproducts} Add ;
  Result

{!alltheproducts} = ";;"

- Update records element
  Find all Opportunity records where

Id Equals {!$Record.OpportunityId} (0065j00000wJCU6AAO)
Update the records’ field values.
Products_on_Opportunity__c = {!toremovecomma} (;;)
Result

All records that meet the filter criteria are ready to be updated when the next screen, pause, or local action is executed or when the interview finishes.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! The SE sites editor  is a bit different from many others you might be used to. Your original post was just a big blob of text. I edited it to attempt to make it more readable, but I do not know if my separations are correct. It is still difficult to follow & understand, to be honest. I suggest *you* [edit] it, click the "?" in the editor (and maybe the "Advanced Help" link you see after clicking the "?"), and format your question to make it more readable. Otherwise if people cannot understand it they cannot help.

Comment: It would also be helpful in this case to add some screenshots of the most important/relevant parts of your Flow.

Comment: Thank you for the edits @moonpie and for your suggestion I will add relevant screenshots and edit it in the question itself

Comment: What happens when you debug? Does `alltheproducts` contain anything? everything? (Please edit your question to add any answers/additional info, rather than answering in a comment.)

Comment: it looks like no one was ever going to help with some answers and yet we need to follow all the rules just for the visible attraction of the post

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. It's not just following the rules to make the post prettier, if that's what you mean. Some people are going to read the main question post & that's it they're not going to read comments - if they don't understand it enough or see enough info they will move on. So if you really want your question answered (answers - especially helpful/correct ones - are *not* guaranteed), you should do everything you can to make it easier for a potential answerer to quickly & easily get a grasp of the issue. If I am misunderstanding your statement, please correct/elaborate.